# Installed GTK+ with homebrew, but pkg_check_modules doesn't recognize it

Tags: c++, c, cmake, homebrew, pkg-config

I'm trying to compile an open source repo, which requires gtk+ in `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
pkg_check_modules (GTK     REQUIRED gtk+-2.0>=2.12)
```

So I installed gtk+-2.0 with homebrew:

```
~  brew install gtk
Warning: gtk+-2.24.23 already installed
```

And to make sure `pkg-config` recognizes it, I've tried:

```
~  pkg-config --modversion gtk+-2.0
2.24.23
```

Which is perfectly right, but when I configure the project with `ccmake ..`, I got the error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.12.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:279 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.12.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:333 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:194 (pkg_check_modules)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

or

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"`

from https://github.com/naxuroqa/Venom/issues/4#issuecomment-27215983

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is install pkg-config :

```
brew install pkg-config
```